# I am having following error in android SDK

Tags: android

the error is in manifest.xml.
Android studio is showing  error that it cannot resolve the symbol `@mipmap/ic_launcher`. I tried to change it to *@drawable* but no luck .Here is my screenshot of android studio-

[image: Android studio screenshot]

Comment: clean and rebuild once

Comment: Please stop posting your question again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder mipmap-hdpi inside res folder. add ic_launcher.png icon in it. rebuild and run project

Answer (score -1):

remove the images from `ic_launcher.png folder` and add directly to the `mipmap` folder. clean then project and run again...hope it will work..